# How to change the join columns based on Condition

Tags: database, oracle, join

How to change the join columns based on the column value , If the column A has value, then the join condition should be t1.a= t2.a, if the A is null value then t1.b=t2.b if both column has values then need to add t1.a= t2.a and  t1.b=t2.b, Please advice

[image]

Comment: Aren't there nulls in Table 2? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
select * 
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where (t1.a is not null and t1.b is not null and t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b) or 
      (t1.a is null     and t1.b is not null and t1.b = t2.b) or 
      (t1.a is not null and t1.b is     null and t1.b = t2.b)
```

Comment: @user2302158 This code is wrong: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ebbdfcf7a718f0507cef5910d0149204

Answer (score 0):

For this sample data use `COALESCE()` to deal with nulls:

```
select *
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t2.A = coalesce(t1.A, t2.A) and t2.B = coalesce(t1.B, t2.B)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=878d585550665eccf40207d0bb4dfc69).
Results:

```
>    A |    B |  A |  B
> ---: | ---: | -: | -:
>    4 | null |  4 |  2
> null |    5 |  5 |  5
>    2 |    2 |  2 |  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query

```
 select * from TABLE1
        inner join TABLE2
        on TABLE1.A=TABLE2.A
        or (select TABLE1.B from TABLE1 where TABLE1.A is null)=TABLE2.B
```

Output

```
A       B       A_1     B_1
----    ----    ----    ---
4       NULL    4       2
NULL    5       NULL    5
2       2       2       2
```